# Non-consumable In App Purchases for Million items

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

**Problem**

I am working on app that has millions digital items . I want to implement **InAppPurchases** for this . So as this is digital content and only once unlock-able/Purchase-able.

**What i have already done.**

I tried to do this via consumable for same price tier but apple rejected my app and forcing to use **non-consumable.

**How to handle the following:**

1 - Do i need to create 30k in App Purchases at iTunes ???? (I read somewhere there is a limit of 10k)

2- Is there a way to reuse one in app purchase for type non-consumable.

Comment: bear in mind your users will expect to restore their previous purchases on other devices, and for that you must implement _non-consumable_ products only; Apple does not care about developer's problems (like e.g. how you'd add 30K products to iTunes, that is your problem, if you could not do it, don't do it, no one cares literally) – they care about the end-users only.

Comment: I had asked this question almost a year ago and being honest i got help too. But today after more than a year ago some guys starting down vote to it. I mean seriously ? If your problem isn't getting solved what this question have to do with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to you to make user buy points, each point opens one item, and whenever user purchases an item, you record it to user's purchases list (for restore purposes).

Comment: that is still not a guarantee for the app would pass the review procedure, if it uses the _consumable_ products on a wrong way.

Comment: I am trying to purchase song for in app purchases so points approach will seems like a cheat and apple will block my account too.

Comment: i think it would be more like games, u're purchasing Points to buy items in game

if you're purchasing a Credit to use it later for whatever you want, it's not some kind of cheating, its same idea as purchasing iTunes cards, you're purchasing credit to use later

Comment: ok , I will discuss this with apple support then implement this in my app.